# Centering an absolute div within an overflow div

Tags: css-position, centering, css

I am looking to center a div that is absolutely positioned inside of an overflow div.

Here is my HTML.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucasjd/kKMbY/)

```
 <header class="contain960"> 
      <div class="brand_logo"></div>
      <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active">Boats</li>
                <li>Cars</li>
                <li>Powersports</li>
                <li>RV's</li>
                <li>Consignment</li>
            </ul>
      </nav>
 </header>

 <div class="site_line top"></div>
 <div class="site_line custom"></div>
 <div class="site_line bottom"></div>
```

And the CSS.

```
section {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  min-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.site_line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 1px
  //Gradient Fill
  //Center the DIV;
}

.site_line.top{
  top: 0px;
}

.site_line.bottom{
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

The .site_line element should always remain centered in the div even as the section gets smaller than 1280px wide and not be pushed to the left. I've done this before with background images and the background-position property. but can't for the life of me figure it out how to do it with out javascript.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe653/15/). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can see an example of the css background-image being centered on this page.  http://www.cartegraph.com/index.php/our-system/meet-cartegraph

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't use `position: absolute;`!

Instead use `margin: auto;`:

```
.site_line {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 1px
  //Gradient Fill
}
```

Comment: Normally I wouldn't. But in this instance I have horizontal lines in the design that overlay the design. Perhaps there is a better structure solution.

Comment: Here is a snapshot of the design I'm working with. [SNAP](http://hawkeyeboat.lucasjdesign.com/assets/img/site_lines_screen.png)

Comment: What is the problem? Yeah I can see some horizontal lines... Do you want them to go?

Comment: They should flow off of both sides not get pushed to the right.